# Right syntax to make a PHP SOAP client

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, client

I need to interact with SOAP (as a client) and am not able to get the syntax right. I've got a WSDL file which allows me to properly set up a new connection using the SoapClient class. However, I'm unable to actually make the right call and get data returned

I've a function defined in WSDL document. The available function and types are these:

```
array([0] => pingResponse ping(ping $parameters))

array(
[0] => struct ping{
PingRQ PingRQ_1;
}
[1] => struct PingRQ{
string code1;
string code2;
string code3;
})
```

I want to make a call to the ping function. What would be the right syntax?